# Download file from REST service using JAX-RS client

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to download a file from a REST service using JAX-RS. 
This is my code which invokes the download by sending a GET request:

```
private Response invokeDownload(String authToken, String url) {
    // Creates the HTTP client object and makes the HTTP request to the specified URL
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target(url);

    // Sets the header and makes a GET request
    return target.request().header("X-Tableau-Auth", authToken).get();
}
```

However I am facing problems converting the Response into an actual File object. So what I did is the following:

```
public File downloadWorkbook(String authToken, String siteId, String workbookId, String savePath)
        throws IOException {
    String url = Operation.DOWNLOAD_WORKBOOK.getUrl(siteId, workbookId);
    Response response = invokeDownload(authToken, url);

    String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
    String filename; 
// some code to retrieve the filename from the headers
    Path path = Files.write(Paths.get(savePath + "/" + filename), output.getBytes());
    File file = path.toFile();
    return file;
}
```

The file which is created is not valid, I debugged the code and noticed that output contains a String like that (much larger):

> PK   ͢�F���� �[    Superstore.twb�ysI�7����ߡ���d�m3��f���

Looks like binary. Obviously there is something wrong with the code.

How do I get the HTTP response body as a string from the Response object?

**Edit:**
Quote from the REST API reference about the HTTP response:

> **Response Body**
>
> One of the following, depending on the format of the workbook:
>
> The workbook's content in .twb format (Content-Type: **application/xml**)
>   The workbook's content in .twbx format (Content-Type: **application/octet-stream**)

Comment: Your file doesn't seem to be a text file. Thus it is not a good idea to create a String from it. Rather use `response.getInputStream()` and write it to the file, e.g. using Apache Commons' `IOUtils.copy(in, out)`.

Comment: This could be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251265/2294429

Comment: @SebastianS you should make that an answer.

Comment: That output looks suspiciously like a zip file.

Comment: @Samuel I wasn't sure, if this is the sole reason (retrieved file could actually still be a text file). Added this as an answer now.

Comment: @SebastianS even if it were a text file, your recommendation is best practice. It could be dangerous to load a potentially large file into memory. InputStreams are the way to go!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you noticed yourself, you're dealing with binary data here. So you shouldn't create a String from your response. Better get the input stream and pipe it to your file.

```
Response response = invokeDownload(authToken, url);
InputStream in = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
Path path = Paths.get(savePath, filename);
Files.copy(in, path);
```

Comment: how do I get the InputStream? there is no method getInputStream()

Comment: Updated my answer. Didn't look the exact API up in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

1) I assume by this point you're clear on the difference between "binary file" and "text file".  And that you can only capture the latter into a "string".

2) Sebastian gave you excellent advice for capturing a binary file (+1, Sebastian!).  VERY IMPORTANT: you should *always* set the MIME type (`Content-Type: xxx/yyy`)in cases like this.  [Here](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2011/11/returning-binary-file-from-rest-service.html) is another link that might be useful.

3) Finally, there are cases where you might *WANT* to treat "binary" data as text.  This is how e-mail attachments work with SMTP (a text protocol).  In these cases, you want to use [Base64 Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  For example: [JAX-RS | Download PDF from Base64 encoded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328068/jax-rs-download-pdf-from-base64-encoded-data)

Comment: 2) I changed the request like this: `target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).header("X-Tableau-Auth", authToken).get()`